# How do I get all records with Field1 matching an arbitrary value while making sure that all values of a DISTINCT query are accounted for in Field2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following (sample) table:

```
 A       DATE       X
---   ----------   ---
aaa   2016-01-01    0
bbb   2016-01-01    1
bbb   2016-01-15    1
aaa   2016-01-15    0
ccc   2016-01-08    1
ccc   2016-01-15    1
ddd   2016-01-01    0
ddd   2016-01-15    0
bbb   2016-01-08    1
ddd   2016-01-08    1
```

My desired result set is as follows:

```
 A       DATE       X
---   ----------   ---
bbb   2016-01-01    1
bbb   2016-01-08    1
bbb   2016-01-15    1
```

Some requirements:

1. `A` contains the group names, `X` is any arbitrary value.
2. `DATE` just contains dates. However, the intervals may vary. This could be daily, weekly, 30 days apart, etc. In any case, the interval WILL ALWAYS be consistent and NO DATE WILL REPEAT for any one group.
3. As you can see, `aaa` and `ccc` only have 2 records each: they don't have data for a specific date. HOWEVER: there will always be ONE group that has all dates, regardless of the value in `X`.
4. Basically, what I want is to find the group/s which have `X` equal to the value I set for all distinct dates in the `DATE` column.

I was thinking of a bit like:

```
SELECT A, DATE, X
FROM t
WHERE X = 1
AND (each) DATE IN (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE) FROM t)
AND (each) X = 1 (for each DATE in SELECT(DISTINCT you get the point)) 
GROUP BY A
```

I can't visualize exactly how to make the *loop* logic work.

**TL;DR:** How do I make sure that each DATE has the necessary value in X and making sure that A has every DATE in the list of DATEs in SQL?

Comment: SQL usually is in contrast to "loop" logic. One can read any runtime condition (WHERE) out loud as "for a_date in (some table expression)" but this is no loop but some set arithmetic. Are you forced to implement a SQL only solution, or would it be possible to separate the task in several SQL queries where some other programming language feeds the results of the first into the latter or finishes the task in itself?

Comment: @Dilettant Sadly, I am forced to use an SQL solution as I have no control over both source and output. If I had it my way, this would have been done in a really easy Python script.

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback. I often overlooked mixed solutions in the past ... ;-)

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: I stand corrected. ;)

Comment: After a while I took this as pseudo code and it helped me together with the prose and sample data to find IMO a nice solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way in MSSQL, try it on yours:

```
SELECT A, DATE, X
FROM Sample
WHERE A IN
(SELECT A
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) AS num_dates 
    FROM Sample
) AS d, 
(
    SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) AS a_num_dates
    FROM Sample
    WHERE X=1
    GROUP BY A
) AS a
WHERE num_dates = a_num_dates)
```

The idea is:

- The table `d` is going to get the number of different dates. It will return `3`, because that is the number of different dates on your sample data (Days 1, 8 and 15).
- The table `a` will get the `A`'s number of distinct dates, but only those whose `X` is `1`.
- Next, we must say that the `A`'s number of distinct dates is equal to the value obtained by `d`. This returns `bbb`.
- Finally, search the Sample table for all lines whose `A` is equal to that value obtained (`bbb`).

Comment: Really quick answer! I will check this right away when I get to my machine. Postgresql is not that different so I doubt this would need heavy conversion.

Comment: On my postgres instance that query also works (only had to translate the table name to the one I created of course).

Comment: Of the two, this actually gave me exactly what I wanted. The other one by @Dilettant worked as well, but this one was far more flexible because there is another transform (a crosstab on the dates!) of the data that was a bit complicated to implement with the other query. This one had a simpler logic to modify. Thanks. +1 and accepted.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for leaving a feedback and taking action. Knowing that an answer helped more or less and why is an important takeaway for when we offer solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is my postgres solution (look at the end of this answer for a single line version):

```
SELECT 
  A, DATE, X 
 FROM t 
 WHERE X = 1 AND A = (
   SELECT A 
    FROM t 
    WHERE X = 1 
    GROUP BY A 
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
   ) 
 ORDER BY DATE
;
```

Details and motivation:

```
$psql> create table t (A VARCHAR(3), DATE DATE, X int);  
CREATE TABLE
```

Insert sample data:

```
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('aaa','2016-01-01',0);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('bbb','2016-01-01',1);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('bbb','2016-01-15',1);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('aaa','2016-01-15',0);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('ccc','2016-01-08',1);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('ccc','2016-01-15',1);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('ddd','2016-01-01',0);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('ddd','2016-01-15',0);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('bbb','2016-01-08',1);
INSERT 0 1
$psql> INSERT INTO t VALUES('ddd','2016-01-08',1);
INSERT 0 1
```

Check all is in:

```
$psql> SELECT * FROM t;
  a  |    date    | x 
-----+------------+---
 aaa | 2016-01-01 | 0
 bbb | 2016-01-01 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-15 | 1
 aaa | 2016-01-15 | 0
 ccc | 2016-01-08 | 1
 ccc | 2016-01-15 | 1
 ddd | 2016-01-01 | 0
 ddd | 2016-01-15 | 0
 bbb | 2016-01-08 | 1
 ddd | 2016-01-08 | 1
(10 rows)
```

Filter where `X == 1`:

```
$psql> SELECT A, DATE, X FROM t WHERE X = 1 ORDER BY A;
  a  |    date    | x 
-----+------------+---
 bbb | 2016-01-01 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-15 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-08 | 1
 ccc | 2016-01-08 | 1
 ccc | 2016-01-15 | 1
 ddd | 2016-01-08 | 1
(6 rows)
```

Check suggested filter at the heart of finding **the** "group" that contains all date values:

```
$psql> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) AS N, A FROM t WHERE X = 1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY N DESC;
 n |  a  
---+-----
 3 | bbb
 2 | ccc
 1 | ddd
(3 rows)
```

The resulting query that should fulfill the described requirements as a one liner:

```
$psql> SELECT A, DATE, X FROM t WHERE X = 1 AND A = (SELECT A FROM t WHERE X = 1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY DATE;
  a  |    date    | x 
-----+------------+---
 bbb | 2016-01-01 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-08 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-15 | 1
(3 rows)
```

**Note**: As @Edu rightfully commented, this is a somehow cool but overly optimistic version, that picks a "dominant" group in tutto. So in case the `bbb` `X` value of `2016-01-08` would have been `0`, than the result would only have 2 rows and **not** mix in another groups entry of that date.

So:

```
$psql>  UPDATE t SET X=0 WHERE DATE = '2016-01-08' AND A != 'ccc';
UPDATE 2
```

Test:

```
$psql> SELECT * FROM t;
  a  |    date    | x 
-----+------------+---
 aaa | 2016-01-01 | 0
 bbb | 2016-01-01 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-15 | 1
 aaa | 2016-01-15 | 0
 ccc | 2016-01-15 | 1
 ddd | 2016-01-01 | 0
 ddd | 2016-01-15 | 0
 bbb | 2016-01-08 | 0
 ddd | 2016-01-08 | 0
 ccc | 2016-01-08 | 1
(10 rows)
```

That results in:

```
$psql> SELECT A, DATE, X FROM t WHERE X = 1 AND A = (SELECT A FROM t WHERE X = 1 GROUP BY A ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY DATE;
  a  |    date    | x 
-----+------------+---
 bbb | 2016-01-01 | 1
 bbb | 2016-01-15 | 1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Your answer is shorter and more efficient. The only thing that **The Laughing Man** should be aware is that they perform differently if there is no `A` that has all dates with `X=1`. This answer returns the one with more dates, even though it doesn't have all, while the answer I gave wouldn't return anything, since it's looking for an `A` that has all dates.

Comment: +1. This works, but see reason above in the answer by @Edu why I chose that one. Thanks, though! I am admittedly weak in SQL, so this is a welcome lesson in "hacking" it.

Comment: Thanks. Cf. my comment on yours at the accepted answer from @Edu.